# When match function doesn't match

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 'CHQ10';
var y = (x.match(/\d+/)[0]);//10
```

When match can identify digit, i got the result.
But in case there is no digit, i got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

```
var x = 'CHQ';    
var y = (x.match(/\d+/)[0]===0)?0:(x.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

I've try with null and undefined but cannot be accepted

Comment: You can't just check `thing[0]`, because `thing` might be null, and trying to read [0] will throw an error.

Comment: `x.match(/\d+/)?.[0]`

Comment: Personally, I'd recomment reading another javascript tutorial - there appear to be some misunderstanding about very basic concepts.

Comment: If you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match, you will find that if there is no match the response will be null, so you want to store the match in a variable first and check if its not null =) 

const does_text_match = x.match(/\d+/);
if(does_text_match ) // Do something

Comment: https://javascript.info/optional-chaining#the-non-existing-property-problem, but tl;dr; what is `null[0]` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match function documentation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

There you will find this:

> Return value
> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.

The error that you are receiving is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
```

That means that you are trying to access the index 0 of something that is not an array, null in this case

Here is an example:

```
    const input_text_that_matches_the_regular_expression = 'CHQ10';
    const input_text_that_does_not_matches_the_regular_expression = 'CHQ';
    const regular_expression = /\d+/
    
    /**
 * If we compare input_text_that_matches_the_regular_expression with the regular expression
 * the 10 will match, and according to the match documentation, we will get an array
 **/
const match = input_text_that_matches_the_regular_expression.match(
  regular_expression,
); // [10] - array of matches, so we can access match[0] to get the first match, which is 10

/**
 * If we compare input_text_that_does_not_matches_the_regular_expression with the regular expression
 * the 10 will not match, and according to the match documentation, we will get null
 */
const match =
  input_text_that_does_not_matches_the_regular_expression.match(
    regular_expression,
); // null  - no matches, if we try to access match[0] we will get an error
```

How to prevent this error?

We have 2 main options, the first one ( more readable )

```
  /**
 * Check with an if statement if the match is null or not
 */
if (match) {
  // do something
} // here you could also add an else statement if needed, this else would mind that there is no match found
```

The second option, as mentioned by CherryDT, is to use a coalesce operator

```
/**
 * You can also use the optional chaining and coalesce operator to get the first match, if there is no match, it will return null
 */
const first_match = match?.[0] ?? null;
```

If you don't know anything about coalesce operator or optional chaining, information can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

and if you need more information about the error itself, this page may help =)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array